Можно ли записывать в регистры со стороны сервера?
Я пишу сервер на pymodbus RTU(Serial). Можно ли сделать запись в регистры со стороны сервера, у меня получилось менять регистры но только до момента запуска сервака, после запуска регистры почему то меняются только со стороны клиента, возможно ли вообще реализовать то что я хочу?
*Судя по всему что нет, ибо сервер запускается со статическим контекстом

Либо есть вариант записывать регистры в БД либо другое хранилище и перезапускать сервер с новым контекстом после каждого изменения но мне кажется это будет вредно для быстродействия, хотя тут надо смотреть

Да, можно. Я использовал StartAsyncSerialServer вместо StartSerialServer, и добавил в асинхронную работу сервера и метод update_registers, который будет читать json с запросов и выполнять их, а так же удалять после успешного изменения
